# Geth JSON-RPC only returns 0, null or error

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I've set up a docker env based upon Ubuntu for working with Geth (for now on Testnet) and Geth's JSON-RPC, however every call I make to the JSON-RPC fails in either 0, null or an error because the method would not exist. Some calls (accounts, gas price) do work on the 'regular' net.

I've set up Geth on the Rinkeby Testnet with the following line:
`geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpcport "8000"`

Here are some examples of what I'm getting back; tried it with both localhost and 127.0.0.1. All in curl, put into the container's own CLI.

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionReceipt","params":["0xb903239f8543d04b5dc1ba6579132b143087c68db1b2168786408fcbce568238"],"id":1}' http://localhost:8000
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":null}

curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getCompilers","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8000
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"The method eth_getCompilers does not exist/is not available"}}

curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_accounts","params":[],"id":2}' http://localhost:8000
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":2,"result":[]}
```

For the last example, to prove there are accounts:

```
 geth account list
 Account #0: {678decf23eb929b88d7a55c272b73aa6e1d0d4bc} keystore:///root/.ethereum/keystore/UTC--2017-10-03T12-56-37.565267100Z--678decf23eb929b88d7a55c272b73aa6e1d0d4bc
```

If someone could help me out, and tell me what the cause could be that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the answer of [SwapnilKumbhar](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/27840/20364) I found out the problem was that the account was not registered in the Rinkeby Testnet, just on the regular net. Specifically registering a new account on the Rinkeby Testnet did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

this issue might occur if you haven't unlocked your account or the miner is nor started

> 1. To unlock account:

open your geth console and run following command

```
personal.unlockAccount("your account key","your passphrase",time in miliseconds)
```

for more:- [API](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal_unlockaccount)

> 2.To run the miner

open your geth console and run following command

```
miner.start(2)
```

After doing this try running your transactions.

Comment: This helped me out a lot, got me to find out the account was only registered on the 'regular' net and not on the Rinkeby testnet, registrering it there did the trick. I'll write an answer it, unfortunately due to low reputation on this SE my upvote is not shown.